# Comsol 2 parameters

Tags: 2d, interpolation, comsol

I have faced with following problem.
I'm solving Boltzmann equation in Comsol using Reduced Field study, thus I vary a field in my program. Moreover I need to vary electron density at the same time. After calculations, I have a results. Derived quantity I want to obtain from the distribution function (EEDF) is rate coefficients, depending on electrical field and electron density. Then I need to use this 2D function (rateCoef(ne,E)) in the next calculations. 
The problem is I cannot extract Rate Coefficient from the solution and export it in a right way. Furthermore I cannot  import data for interpolation in the next program because comsol doesn't like it that coordinates in table are the same. 
Here is the example of the table:

n1, E1, f1

n2, E1, f2

n3, E1, f3

...

n1, E2, f...

and so on.

Thanks!